# CSS - How to scale image and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have an image

```
<div class="frame-2">
    <img class="police" alt="police" src="img/police.png">
</div>
```

And I want to scale it to ~50%, but I don't want to zoom-out the image.

```
@keyframes house {
0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
}
100% {
    transform: translateX(-20px) translateY(-80px) scale(0.47, 0.56);
}
```

I scale it with animation and it's going from 300x250 to 141x141. I want to keep aspect ratio, but show only part of image, like zoomed.

Comment: If you want to keep the aspect ratio, why are the horizontal and vertical scale factors different?

Comment: Also, which element is the animation defined on? Your code doesn't say if it's the div or the img.

Comment: I want to scale image without zoom-out it.

Comment: http://s22.postimg.org/45da41227/image.png

Comment: It's very hard to do what you want to do purely with CSS and have it work nicely on all browsers. I recommend you find an appropiate JS library to provide said functionality.